# tried check valid palindrom string problem solving using kotlin but there is one of the testcase is not passed i tried several times

Tags: kotlin, palindrome

this is the problem
A phrase is a palindrome if, after converting all uppercase letters into lowercase letters and removing all non-alphanumeric characters, it reads the same forward and backward. Alphanumeric characters include letters and numbers.

Given a string s, return true if it is a palindrome, or false otherwise.

Example 1:

Input: s = "A man, a plan, a canal: Panama"
Output: true
Explanation: "amanaplanacanalpanama" is a palindrome.
Example 2:

Input: s = "race a car"
Output: false
Explanation: "raceacar" is not a palindrome.

myCode

```
class Solution {
      fun isPalindrome(s:String):Boolean {
    var s1 = s.toLowerCase()
    var myStringBuilder = StringBuilder()
    var n = s1.length-1
    var n1=myStringBuilder.length

    for ( i in 0..n) {
        if (Character.isLetterOrDigit(s1[i])) {
            myStringBuilder.append(s1[i])
        }
    }
     for( i in 0 .. (n1/2)-1){
            if(myStringBuilder[i] != myStringBuilder[n1-i-1]){
                return false
            }
     } 
        return true
}
}
```

the first case passed
but this is not passed as per the result Input: s = "race a car result true expected is false

Answer (score 1):

You can use this simple solution.

```
fun isPalindrome(s:String):Boolean {
    val str = s.filter { it.isLetterOrDigit() }.lowercase()
    for (i in 0..str.length/2 ){
        if (str[i]!=str[str.length-i-1])
            return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Edit:
By the [@cactustictacs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13598222/cactustictacs) comment, you can do this in much more simple way.

```
fun isPalindrome(s:String):Boolean {
    val str = s.filter { it.isLetterOrDigit() }.lowercase()
    return str == str.reversed()
}
```

Comment: You can do ``return str == str.reversed()`` too

Answer (score 1):

You're initialising `n1` too early:

```
// create an -empty- StringBuilder
var myStringBuilder = StringBuilder()
...
// since it's empty, n1 == 0
var n1=myStringBuilder.length
```

You're setting it to the length of the `StringBuilder` contents before you've actually put anything in it. This is a simple value you're setting, it's not a reference to the `length` getter that will give the current value when you access it. You set it once and that's its value forever.

So your last loop, the one that checks if it's a palindrome or not, never actually runs:

```
// since n1 is 0, this is for (i in 0..0)
for( i in 0 .. (n1/2)-1){
```

You can fix it by initialising `n1` when you've finished adding your content to the `StringBuilder`, so you can get its final length:

```
for ( i in 0..n) {
    if (Character.isLetterOrDigit(s1[i])) {
        myStringBuilder.append(s1[i])
    }
}

// StringBuilder is complete, grab its final length
var n1 = myStringBuilder.length

// now you can use it
for (i in 0..(n1/2)-1) {
```

---

Just fyi, there's also an `until` operator that works like `..` except it doesn't include the last value of the range. So you can write

`for (i in 0 until (n1/2))`

if you want!

Comment: i have edited the code but still get the same result  class Solution {
      fun isPalindrome(s:String):Boolean {
    var s1 = s.toLowerCase()
    var myStringBuilder = StringBuilder()
    var n = s1.length
    

    for ( i in 0 until n) {
        if (Character.isLetterOrDigit(s1[i])) {
            myStringBuilder.append(s1[i])
        }
    }
    
    var n1=myStringBuilder.length
          
     for( i in 0 until (n1/2)-1){
            if(myStringBuilder[i] != myStringBuilder[n1-i-1]){
                return false
            }
     } 
        return true
}
}

Comment: @Beginnerdeveloper I can't really read that, but I see you're using `until` while still doing the `-1`. That's the point of `until`, instead of doing `start..end-1` you can do `start until end` - the `until` basically *includes* the `-1` by skipping the last element, unlike `..`. Your code works with the change I suggested, if you're still having trouble compare what you've got to this: https://pl.kotl.in/RFhr4Z1MC